# python psycopg2 query error timestamp without time zone

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

From my python code i had the method:

```
def start_db(event, context):

    conn = db()

    cur = conn.cursor()



    datada = event['data_start']
    dataa = event['data_stop']

    if not datada or not dataa:
        dataa = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        datada = str(dataa - datetime.timedelta(days=7))      

    s_query = "SELECT * FROM a_usage WHERE (bk_tenant = '%s', data_start LIKE '%s'::timestamp, data_stop LIKE '%s'::timestamp);" % (event['bk_tenant'], datada, dataa)
    cur.execute(s_query)
    A = cur.fetchone()

    conn.commit()

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    return A
```

but when i run my code (db is postgreSQL) an error occur:

> operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ timestamp without time zone

what's wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear why you are trying to use `LIKE` on timestamps but this cannot work as the operator needs textual arguments.

You can use equality operator on timestamps:

```sql
WHERE 
    bk_tenant = '%s' 
    AND data_start = '%s'::timestamp 
    AND data_stop = '%s'::timestamp
```

or `LIKE` on texts:

```sql
WHERE 
    bk_tenant = '%s' 
    AND data_start::text LIKE '%s' 
    AND data_stop::text LIKE '%s'
```

Note also that you should use Boolean operators `AND` instead of commas.